# disable mouse events on click for (this) and re-enable them for ('.class').not(this) - jquery

Tags: mouseevent, jquery, jquery-click-event

I need to keep the color of the clicked div until another div of the same class gets clicked. Right now I have this code:

```
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#dddddd');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#888888');
});
$('.aaa').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#555555');
    $('.aaa').not(this).css('background', '#111111');
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('.aaa').not(this).on('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jUP7/

Only problem here is that I can't re-enable previously disabled events (for previously clicked elements).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your handlers in functions, to make it easy to refer to them in multiple places.

```
$(".aaa").on({
    mouseenter: mouseEnter,
    mouseleave: mouseLeave
});

function mouseEnter() {
    $(this).css('background', '#dddddd');
}
function mouseLeave() {
    $(this).css('background', '#888888');
}
$(".aaa").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#555555');
    $(".aaa").not(this).css('background', '#111111');
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(".aaa").not(this).on({
        mouseenter: mouseEnter,
        mouseleave: mouseLeave
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5jUP7/1/)

Comment: @weaponx Although this answers your orinigal question of disabling and enabling mouse enter, what you are trying to achieve would be a lot simpler using simple CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jUP7/4/)

You can do most of your work using simple CSS

HTML

```
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
```

CSS

```
.aaa {
    display:block;
    background:#888;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.aaa:hover,
.aaa.disabled:hover{
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;
}
.aaa.active {
    background:#111;
}
.aaa.disabled {
    background:#555;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.aaa').click(function () {
    $('.aaa').removeClass('active disabled');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.aaa').not($(this)).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. this works, but it currently isn't the approach I use, which is visible in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable anything. Just keep track of the previously clicked element.

```
var lastObjClicked;
function clicked(this){
  var thisClass = this.className;

  if( lastObjClicked.className == thisClass){
    document.getElementById(lastObjClicked.id).style.color = '#FF0000';
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.color = '#FF0000';

  }else{
    lastObjClicked = this;
  }
}
```